# How to update nested JSON with mongo/node/mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My front end is setup with React, and I am using MongoDB for my database, node/express and mongoose ODM.

All of my data is basically nested JSON essentially like this.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "stringA": "a random string",
      "stringB": "another random string",
      "someArray": [
          {
              "id": 0,
              "stringInArray": 3,
              "nestedArrayOne": [
                  {
                  "id": 0,
                  "stringInNestedArray": "asdasd",
                  },
                  {
                      "id": 1,
                      "string2InNestedArray": "asdasd",
                  }
               ]
          },
          {
              "id": 1,
              "stringInArray": 3,
              "nestedArrayTwo": [
                  {
                      "id": 0,
                      "anotherNestArray": [
                          {
                             "stringInNestedArray": "string"
                          }
                       ]
                   }
           }
      ]
}
```

I apologize if that is difficult to understand. Anyways, I have setup several routes in my Node/express server using mongoose. Get, put and post requests are easy at the top level.

```
myRouter.route('/')
.get((req, res, next) => {
    Data.find()
    .then(data=> {
        console.log('getting all incidents');
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.json(data);
    })
    .catch(err => next(err));
})
.post((req, res, next) => {
    MyRouter.create(req.body)
    .then(data=> {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.json(data);
    })
    .catch(err => next(err));
})
```

Second level isn't so bad.

```
myRouter.route('/:id')
.get((req, res, next) => {
    Data.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(data=> {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.json(data);
    })
    .catch(err => next(err));
})
.put((req, res, next) => {
    Data.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
        $set: req.body
    }, { new: true })
    .then(data=> {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.json(data);
    })
    .catch(err => next(err));
})
```

Once I start getting into routes where I am accessing nested arrays such as

```
myRouter.route('/:id/array/:arrayId')

or

myRouter.route('/:id/array/:arrayId/anotherArray')
```

I have no idea where to even start. For a POST request for the first array that I come to I have this code that works fine.

```
myRouter.route('/:id/array')
.post((req, res, next) => {
    Data.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(data=> {
        if (data) {
            data.myArray.push(req.body);
            data.save()
            .then(data=> {
                res.statusCode = 200;
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                res.json(data.myArray[data.myArray.length-1]);
            })
            .catch(err => next(err)); 
        } else{
            err = new Error(`Incident ${req.params.id} not found`);
            err.status = 404;
            return next(err);
        }
    })
    .catch(err => next(err));
})
```

Like I said, that POST request works fine; I push data into what starts out as an empty array, save it and then return the last (most recent) entry that I pushed into the array.

Is this the correct way of going about this? What if I want to push data into a nested array within that previous array? (ie myRouter.route('/:id/array/:arrayId/anotherArray'))

I am trying to use the built-in Mongoose functions such as "findById" and "findByIdAndUpdate" however, I can only access the first id in my route and not the id's of my nested arrays as far as I can tell.

Is there a proper way to post new data and update old data in nested arrays without having to basically search the main object, then the first array, then the next array, then the next array then push my data?

I hope this wasn't too terrible to understand, I appreciate the help! Thanks.

Comment: Your goal is to basically add or remove `someArray` instances to a `Data` entity, correct?

Comment: I want to be able to add more objects to the nested arrays. Each array is going to consist of several strings, numbers as well as an array of objects. Some of those objects will have another array or two (both containing objects as well).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update nested array you need use `$push` to update array.

Reference:

- https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/pushing-array-of-elements-to-nested-array-in-mongo-db-schema/112494